# Python MusicalBeeps Causing Errors

Tags: python

I started using the module [MusicalBeeps](https://pypi.org/project/MusicalBeeps/) to try and play music in Python, however, whenever I try making a player play a noise, I get a huge error. My code looks like this right now:

```
import musicalbeeps as music

global TempPlayer

def PlayNote(Note, Octive, Accidental, Duration, Volume):
  #Accidental is either # (sharp) or b (flat) or '' (none)
  global TempPlayer
  TempPlayer = music.Player(volume = float(Volume), mute_output = False)
  TempPlayer.play_note("{}{}{}".format(Note, Octive, Accidental), Duration)
  TempPlayer = None

print("Running...")
PlayNote("B", 4, "#", 5, 1)
print("Done!")
```

This is the example they showed on the website, however whenever I try to run it I get this weird error:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    PlayNote("B", 4, "#", 5, 1)
  File "main.py", line 9, in PlayNote
    TempPlayer.play_note("{}{}{}".format(Note, Octive, Accidental), Duration)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/musicalbeeps/beepsplayer.py", line 138, in play_note
    self.__write_stream(duration)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/musicalbeeps/beepsplayer.py", line 118, in __write_stream
    self._play_obj = sa.play_buffer(audio, 1, 2, self.rate)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simpleaudio/shiny.py", line 60, in play_buffer
    play_id = _sa._play_buffer(audio_data, num_channels, bytes_per_sample,
_simpleaudio.SimpleaudioError: Error opening PCM device. -- CODE: -2 -- MSG: No such file or directory
```

BTW I'm using [repl.it](http://repl.it) to make this, and I've already downloaded the musicbeeps module into the file.

Please help, I'm just trying to make a simple project

Comment: Code on `repl.it` is running on a server, somewhere far away from you.  Even if that server had audio hardware connected, *you wouldn't be able to hear it*.

Comment: @jasonharper, so if I was to run this code in Terminal or another app on my computer, it would work?

Comment: Possibly, I don't know what the system requirements are for this module you're trying to use, it may require a specific platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the links to the installed package - it makes it easier to find a solution.  MusicalBeeps depends on simpleaudio which requires (on linux at least - and as you posted ALSA errors, I'll assume this is Linux) the libasound2-dev development library to be installed.  See https://simpleaudio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#linux-dependencies